Property does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'
I have an angular library that has a react component inside it.
I want my react component ABC to use an angular component XYZ using createCustomElement.
The createCustomElement logic is inside an app module later and is not present in my library, I have added polyfills so that the ABC does not throw error and the build runs successfully.
Before running the build, it shows no error, on hovering over <xyz></xyz> in abc.tsx file, it even displays that it is present JSX.IntrinsicElements["custom-element"]: any
This is my polyfill code:
declare global {

  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      
      "custom-element": any;
    }
  }
}

It is correctly added in my angular.json as well.
How to resolve this issue so that my build runs successfully?
